# What does curl_multi_getcontent($ch) return if $ch isn't ready?

Tags: php, curl

What does curl_multi_getcontent($ch) return if $ch isn't ready in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the question you asked is

- If the response has not been received yet, `curl_multi_getcontent` returns `NULL`.
- If the transfer is in progress, `curl_multi_getcontent` returns the data retrieved so far.

The question you meant to ask, apparently, is this: **How do I know when a `curl_multi...` operation is finished?**

The answer is that you don't use `curl_multi_getcontent` for this. Instead, repeatedly call `curl_multi_exec` until the second parameter (which is the number of sub-handles still working on its transfer) goes to 0. [This blog post](http://www.rustyrazorblade.com/2008/02/curl_multi_exec/), from the comments in the manual, shows some working code. You may also want to look at `curl_multi_select`, which will block until there's some activity on a connection. This probably leads to fewer cycles wasted making `curl_multi_exec` calls: See example #1 on the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) for `curl_multi_exec`.

If you're using version 5.2.0 or later, you can use `curl_multi_info_read` to get the status of individual connections instead of waiting for all of them. [(manual)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php)

Comment: Hmm...  I may have hit 'accept' a little too soon.  It seems when I use the condition that curl_multi_getcontent($ch) !== NULL i get just the first several lines of the page and then it breaks.  I assume it's still downloading and I get the information a little too early.

Comment: As mentioned originally (and now further explained), you should be testing the result of `curl_multi_exec` to see if it's equal to `CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM`, before you even call `curl_multi_getcontent`.

Comment: What about when I want to know if a single handle in the multi-handle is finished?

Comment: See the last sentence about using `curl_multi_info_read`? If you're running pre-5.2.0, then you might try calling `curl_getinfo` on the individual handle(s).