# How do I do cURL download and output in parallel with PHP?

Tags: php, file, download, save, readfile

I trying to make download redirect useing PHP.
I am getting the file through anther server

For example: http://rarlab.com/rar/wrar420.exe

I want the Script Save the file as temp variable and in the same time he save, 
he Send it to the browser as download...

```
function download($url,$name,$hash){ 
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$name);  
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($url);
}
download("http://rarlab.com/rar/wrar420.exe","winrar.rar","26digitHASH");
```

THX you guys.

Comment: it is, i want it to do it in the same time,
what really happening is:
making the curl request, and when its done,send the download..

Comment: I think with this addition it is a real question... and a rather common one... and an interesting technique: "How do I do cURL download and output in parallel with PHP?" Voted for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is almost out of the scope PHP is made for, but thanks to the multi handle feature of the cURL implementation it should be possible.

See the documentation of [curl_multi_exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) on how to use the multi handle functionality.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689183/what-does-curl-multi-getcontentch-return-if-ch-isnt-ready) it is possible to call [curl_multi_getcontent()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-getcontent.php) before the transfer is finished:

```
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }

    // echo the contents downloaded so far
    // Note that this must be called with the curl handle, not with the multi handle.
    echo curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
    flush();

}
```

Comment: emm look nice, but I have only need with 1 curl request, how can i mix it with my function?

Comment: You need to create a multi handle, even if you only link a single curl handle to it. In your pastebin you curl_exec and curl_close your curl handle - don't do that, the multi handle will do that for you.

Comment: ohhh, its work, but the download speed is pretty slow..
what can i do to make it faster?
(got root).

Comment: Measure, measure, measure. What is slow? Watch CPU load. Make a log with microsecond timestamps and downloaded bytes.

Comment: What are you doing there... Only send the `header`s once, remove `readfile` and `ob_clean` and learn about what they do. Try the download 1) without the `curl_multi_getcontent($ch)` and then 2) with the `curl_multi_getcontent($ch);` but without the `echo` and `flush()`.

Comment: what do you mean? can you make me an example?